# Can the Flash Builder 4.5 iPad simulator be scaled?

Tags: debugging, apache-flex, flex4

I'm working on an Adobe Flash Builder 4.5 iPad application.  I have only a humble 13" MacBook to work with.

I am being aggravated by the problem of debugging my application in the Flashbuilder's  iPad simulator.  The FB simulator screen is almost the same physical size as a real iPad, which is too big to fit on a 13" MacBook.

QUESTION:  Is there some setting in Flash Builder 4.5 that would scale the iPad simulator to fit the available screen real estate?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the resolution of your Macbook or use the physical device to do development.  I don't think it's possible to 'scale' the emulator, nor would you want to.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know of a way for you to actually scale it, you can get around some of the problems by just rotating it (Command-R)